# Split View Controller with Multiple Details View - Memory Leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have added two view controllers before moving to split view controller. In split view controller as the details controllers are changing, memory usage is increasing according to newly allocated view controller memory usage. But, Previous Detail View Controllers' memory are not automatically released by ARC. In simulator I have checked with simulated memory warnings, but ARC never releases those unused view controllers' memory. Due to increasing memory usage app crashes. 
I checked splitViewController.viewControllers array and inner array but never find out unused details view controllers' instance.
I have tried with @autorelease block. It didn't work.

Please get me out of this nightmare.